# JS Change CSS Nested tr

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking to do this:

```
.LoanAppLine:nth-of-type(5) tr {
...
}
```

but in JavaScript. I tried this but am not sure how to get it to work.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('LoanAppLine')[5] tr.style.display = 'none';
```

I just want to change the CSS in the nested tr's.

Comment: So remember in Javascript, Arrays, NodeLists, etc., are 0-based, so `...[5]` is actually the 6th item. Try `....[4]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all elements matching a selector and use `forEach` to loop over it.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".LoanAppLine:nth-of-type(5) tr").forEach(x => x.style.display = "none");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of `getElementsByClassName()`. The newer `querySelector()` returns the first element that matches the specified CSS selector. You could use:

```
document
  .querySelector('.LoanAppLine:nth-of-type(5) tr')
  .style
  .display = 'none'
```

If you have more than one element, you can use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead which returns a NodeList (a list of elements that matches your selector). NodeLists have a [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method you can use to iterate over the elements:

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('.LoanAppLine:nth-of-type(5) tr')
  .forEach(el => el.style.display = 'none')
```